# Blackberry User-Agent and https Redirect url

Tags: apache, blackberry, https, httpclient, httpconnection

I tried to access a HTTPS connection by entering the value in browser, it seems to work fine and redirects me to expected page/output. But when I tried the same using the code, I am unable to get the result. I tried of setting the UserAgent as (Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9800; en-GB) AppleWebKit/534.1+ (KHTML, like  Gecko) Version/6.0.0.141 Mobile Safari/534.1+). But no luck. I am getting trusted connection alert, when i click continue i get response code 302.How can i implement secure connection certificate to disable trusted connection alert.

I am used to httpsconnection to open url it returns the response code 302.Again i checked with

```
if (rc == HttpConnection.HTTP_TEMP_REDIRECT
            || rc == HttpConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
            || rc == HttpConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM) {
    String location = conn.getHeaderField("location").trim();
    System.out.println("location========"+location);
    try {
        Url = location;
        newhttpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(Url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        newhttpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        newhttpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
                System.getProperty("browser.useragent"));
    } catch (Exception e) {                               
        System.out.println( e.toString());            
    }
```

But no use i am getting same 302 from redirect url.

**EDITED:**

Also please give some ideas to get the functions equivalent to HTTPClient to be work in HTTPSConnection. How can i get those functionalities. If there is no possibility to use Httpclient in blackberry then how can i  utilize Blackberry https connection equivalent to Httpcleint (or) to get the automatic redirect using HTTPS Connection?

When connector.open(url) excutes i am getting like this

```
SSL:->CH
SSL:<-SH
SSL:<-SC
SSL:<-SHD
TLS:->CKE
SSL:->CCS
TLS:->F
TLS:<-F
```

in output console then wrong response displayed.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting trusted connection alert, when i click continue i get response code 302.

This is a fully expected behaviour.

[302 means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) the requested resource is on some other URI. In other words server instructs you to execute a redirect. You should investigate connection headers and in the one named "Location" you will find a new URI to continue with. Close/finalize you current connection and start a new one for the just got redirect URI.

**UPDATE**:

Usually good servers respond with HTTP 302 after a successful POST. This is a known [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to prevent users from posting the same data twise on browser page refresh (user may press F5 in a desktop browser). So if the page you are accessing via POST is designed for usual browsers, then this may just mean your POST was successful and you don't need to execute a redirecting request. At least, if you need the response for some result evaluation then don't redirect using a POST, this time use a GET.

Comment: Thank you for useful suggestions. I want to send Browser information in useragent to the url then it give correct output.So i used os6.0 and tried in browser i got proper output. In the same manner i posted useragent in httpconnection and got 302 response then i used GET method but am getting same 302 response.

Comment: I used conn.getHeaderField("location").trim() to get the redirect url.Is it correct way ? then i used new method for Http GET but no use.

Comment: userAgent = System.getProperty("browser.useragent");   
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",userAgent);

Comment: @Gopinath: Odd thing is that I've never had to set "User-Agent" in BB. It just always works for me as is. Anyway, I believe location should start from a capital letter: `conn.getHeaderField("Location")`.

Comment: My client says that "you need to enable JS code in app since browser redirects correctly". How to enable js in https POST code.

Comment: @Gopinath: Please ask another question about this new requirement.

Comment: Is there any way to disable the trusted connection alert through code.I think i got wrong response because of this trusted connection alert.Andriod uses ssl and trusted manager to disable the alert so they getting correct response.

Comment: @Gopinath: I maybe wrong but if I remember correctly once I select "Continue" then this alert do not appear any longer on the device for that host.

Comment: For the Redirect in blackberry,We tried in Andriod and java by using httpclient we got corrrect response. But in blackberry we added (apache-jakarta-commons-httpclient.jar)as external JAR,we are getting "'apache-jakarta-commons-httpclient' not found" error.Help me how can add this jar file or any alternate in blackberry to achieve httpclient functionalities.In addition for BB we tried httpDemo http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-HTTP-Connection-code-and-BIS-B-Access/m-p/798649#M144815 sample it keep on redirecting and shows wrong response.

Comment: @Gopinath: it is impossible to use apache-jakarta-commons-httpclient.jar because it uses core Java classes (e.g. ArrayList) that do not exist in BB Java API.

Comment: @Gopinath: Sorry I am not aware of such.

Comment: Please give some ideas to get the functions equivalent to HTTPClient to be work in HTTPSConnection. How can i get those functionalities