# Enable javascript in https or http POST blackberry

Tags: javascript, http, blackberry, https

I am trying to connect https connection using POST method. OS version is 6.0 when i called my url in broswer am getting correct response but in my app i am getting wrong response. I want to send User-Agent in post.

```
conn = (HttpsConnection) Connector.open(Url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpsConnection.POST);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9800; en-GB) AppleWebKit/534.1+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.0.141 Mobile Safari/534.1+");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", ""+userAgent.getBytes().length);
URLEncodedPostData oPostData = new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false);

oPostData.append("User-Agent",userAgent);
OutputStream finalOut = conn.openOutputStream();   
finalOut.write(oPostData.getBytes()); 
finalOut.flush();    
finalOut.close();           
rc = conn.getResponseCode();
```

i am getting response code 302 but its wrong response.So my client says "you need to enable JS code in app since browser redirects correctly".
Please help me how to enable JS in code ?

Answer (score 0):

You're making a direct single http connection to the server and you'll get back a single response (if the connection succeeded).  Nothing to do with Javascript since you're not using a browser.

The 302 is a redirect response; it means the server wants the client to connect somewhere else.  I don't remember OTTOMH if BB's Connector supports automatic redirects but if so you likely want to enable that.

Comment: The andriod code which works well is .KeyStore trustStore KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustStore.load(null, null);SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);   sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);WebView ua = new WebView(this).getSettings().getUserAgentString();HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, ua); HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
   HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
   HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
   HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, ua);

Comment: But BB gives wrong response.How do i enable JS and set User-Agent in my https POST ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a simular situation on my native BB app that I'm building.  Turns out the issue, in part, is which particular "communicaiton channel" you're using to connect to the network?  As you have certainly come to learn, BB has about 6 different channels (not counting USB or Bluetooth), and each has its own way of setting up and establishing the connection between the handset and the backend.

Take a look at the ConnectionFactory, preferred Transport types, ConnectionDescriptors, and other related classes to help make this simple.

Next, where this becomes an issue for you - as it did with me - is depending upon what connection you ultimately use to connect you might receive a 302 Redirection error from the Server.  Not a big problem if that does happen ... simply check for the existence of a "Location" header field that will get added which will let you know the new URL you should use to get to the desired resource.

.... something along these lines:

```
if (httpCon.getResponseCode() == 302 && httpCon.getHeaderField("Location") != null)
{
    String redirectedURL = httpCon.getHeaderField("Location");
    // use this in your communications to get your content.
}
```

Comment: In andriod and iphone http connection have automatic redirect option but for blackberry we want to redirect manually.So i manually redirected and i posted questions regarding for that "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094615/blackberry-user-agent-and-https-redirect-url". But no use, i dont know why BB is not working fine where in andriod and iphone works well.
So i am trying to enable JS in code. I referred "http://codetrips.blogspot.com/2007/04/http-post-from-j2me-midlet.html" too for post connection.

Comment: Hai CirrusFlyer can you please provide me the code which you overcome the https problem